# Getting index.php listing instead of website

Tags: php, ubuntu-16.04

My setup was

```
Ubuntu 14.04
php 5.x
```

The website was working fine.

I upgraded the system to:

```
Ubuntu 16.03
php 7
```

When I do:

```
php -v
```

I get:

```
PHP 7.0.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 (cli) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
with Zend OPcache v7.0.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies
```

I have:

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   2017-09-18T15:09:02
```

But, when I try to access the website, I now see a listing of the file index.php in the browser window.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using nginx or apache?

Comment: I am using Apache

Answer (score 0):

You should add a `.htaccess` file to the directory root with the line `DirectoryIndex index.php index.html` which tells Apache to use `index.php` first followed by `index.html` when in a directory, which is why you're seeing a directory listing of `index.php`

Comment: Did that and rebooted the server, still the same problem. It was working fine before the server was upgraded to Ubuntu 16.04 and php 7